# I am getting error in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Normally in core php if we try to make a request using ajax we set url of the file where the query exist so when switching same process in codeigniter but I got an error in response can anyone help me out with this error

net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

here is my code 
 Javascript ajax

```
$.ajax ({
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "https://localhost:90/tufuturo/home/register",
                data     : {username: username, email: email, password: confirm_password},
                dataType : "text",
                success  : function(data, text, xhr) {
                    if(xhr == 200) {
                        var return_data = data;
                        $('#messagebox').fadeIn(2000, function() {
                            $(this).html("<div class='message'>"+return_data+"</div>").delay(4000).fadeOut(3000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is the code form my Home.php controller

```
public function register() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', '', 'required|trim|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', '', 'md5|trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = array(
                'username'   => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password'   => $this->input->post('password'),
                'email'      => $this->input->post('email'),
                'type'       => 'user'
            );

            $this->data_insert->add_admin($data);
            echo 'New admin has been successfully created';
        } else {
            echo 'Username already taken';
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how can i get rid of this error

Comment: Why you use https in local system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your localhost is not conforming `https` protocol

Change the url from `https://localhost:90/tufuturo/home/register`
to `http://localhost:90/tufuturo/home/register`

If you want to work with `https` protocol you need to [generate certificate](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/generate-a-csr-with-openssl/)

Comment: when i changed https to http nothing is happening now should i remove http as well?

Comment: No, are you sure about the port `90` you are listening to?

Comment: yes how can i verify if i am getting any response will echo work in controller will it give us response ? Yes I am sure as i run file directly from browser it is working

Comment: version is 3.0 is the one i am using

Comment: and you sure you set the settings to translate url? It won't auto translate to /controller/method, default is `index.php?/controller/method`

Comment: never heared about this settings where is the file located

Comment: i figured out the thing though when i have removed this condition if(xhr == 200) { it is working fine so xhr response code 200 is not working though

Comment: Hmm, you better use `json` and set some `result` flag instead of checking http header status `(is equal:200)`, because these headers are more communication\OS errors

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSL(https), maybe you need take :90 out of your url.

Comment: You can use `https` over port `90`, the default is `443` but you can listen to any port you want (as long as it is available)

Comment: I am using 90 because of skype if i run skype wamp server stops so that is why i changed my port to 90